# How long is long code

Tags: discussion, code-length

I usually hang out at the JavaScript tag, with a mix of jQuery, HTML and CSS where the code reviewed are usually snippets, which run around 100 lines and code that needs micro-optimizations. These are all fine, and one can answer them in a 15 min coffee break.

But sometimes I come across review questions that are one of these:

- entire libraries
- whole webpages
- a full project
- multiple files
- some other huge code

So I ask the following:

- How long is *long code*?
- How many files does it take to call it *long code*?
- Should we cater these *long code*?

Comment: Here's a [different but related question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60/what-is-the-appropriate-length-of-a-code-review-question) with the following outcome: when a code is longer than it should be, it's OK to answer to explain that it's too long and what can be done to make it shorter.

Answer (score 13):

I think our policy is that you are allowed to post as much code as you want, so long as it fits in the question. You are encouraged to narrow the focus of your code in the interest of getting better answers. So it's helpful if you only post the snippets you really want a review of, but its not required. You'll get better answers if you only post the smaller portions.

Comment: Is it OK to review, say, 10% of that code?

Comment: @QuentinPradet, sure.